# ¿Cómo puedo validar la fecha de un .CER del sat para ver si no esta caduco? en PHP

Tags: php, php5

Tengo un formulario donde pido un .CER de una persona pero quisiera evitar que suban uno que ya haya caducado pues luego no tienen presente ese dato y genera problemas en el sistema que estoy creando.
La información viene pues Windows lo puede ver
[image: Aquí un ejemplo]

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando php puedes utilizar Openssl para parsear el Certificado y obtener los datos de este.

```
$my_file = 'cert.cer';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'r');
$data = fread($handle,filesize($my_file));
```

Pero primero debes codificar el archivo y ponerlo en formato PEM, ya que los archivos del SAT vienen en binario.

```
$encoded = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".base64_encode($data)."\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

Finalmente la función openssl_x509_parse regresará un arreglo con todos los datos que contiene.

```
$cert_info = openssl_x509_parse($encoded);

.
.
.
string(13) "160811144237Z"
["validTo"]=>
string(13) "200811144317Z"
["validFrom_time_t"]=>
int(1470926557)
["validTo_time_t"]=>
int(1597156997)
.
.
.
```

Comment: Esta respuesta debe considerarse como la correcta.